# InfoPath 2013: Parent child InfoPath form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I am trying to figure out how to implement Parent and child relationship in InfoPath 2013.
My scenario like this:

Create New Item (via InfoPath) Parent Form (I have Complete)
the Infopath contain the header for instance 
ProjectId, ProjectName, and ProjectOwner, and task that need to complete for instance:

- Setup username
- Setup Phone
- Setup email account

Then i need to create Child Form (Not sure how)
The information include ProjectId, ProjectName, ProjectOwner retrieve from Parent Infopath Form, then i have series of task including:

- Induction Process
- Setting up payment detail

Please advise how i can achieve this in InfoPath 2013. Thank you